# Getting 'Stale NFS file handle' when Mounting Amazon EBS Drive/Volume

Tags: amazon-ec2, nfs, amazon-ebs

I had some issues this morning with an EC2 instance so I stopped it and changed it's type and it seemed to unmount one of my drives.

Now, I can't mount anything, including freshly created, attached and formatted drives.

I keep getting the same error:

```
mount: Stale NFS file handle
```

I don't even think I'm using NFS ...

Any ideas on how to solve this?

**Update & Resolution**

Added my own answer below.

Comment: I've google the crap out of this and NOTHING seems to be working.

Comment: I realise it's totally unhelpful, but last time i got this error it was about 2 years ago on a server that didn't even use NFS, so in that respect its a total red herring. I can't for the life of me remember what the fix was though.

Comment: Damn. That's exactly my case. I don't use NFS...

Comment: At a guess, try running a fsck on the root filesystem. I'm guessing being amazon you'll have to attach it to another instance. That sounds like the sort of thing i'd have tried to fix it.

Comment: I've somehow managed to recover the disk and updated the question with how I was able to resolve it.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. If you resolved your own issue, please post the answer and then accept it, so that others who read the question know that it has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update & Resolution**

As Sirex mentions below, the Stale NFS file handle is a red herring (I'm not using NFS).

Here is what I had to do resolve the issue:

- STOP the instance running with the OS and Data drive disk attached
- Detach both the OS and Data volume
- Make snapshots of each and then create new volumes from the snapshots
- Create new instance
- Attach the newly created from snapshot OS and Data Volume and run fsck on both volumes
- Shutdown new instance and detach all volumes
- Attach the OS volume to /dev/sda1 to the new instance (making it the boot drive) and the Data volume as /dev/sdf (or whatever you want)
- Mount your Data volume and pray for no errors
- If it all works - GO MAKE SNAPSHOTS AGAIN NOW! :)

Hope this helps the next googler.